# How to translate Cell Values in the Silverlight DataGrid?

Tags: silverlight

Please, recommend any best approach to how to translate 
Cell Values in the Silverlight `DataGrid` without changing databases.

I.e. content "FullName" of the cell Nombre should be in

English: Full Name

Spanish: Nombre Completo and etc.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Maintain a resource file with translated values eg two files one with english other with french and set the current culture to the language you want to show

Comment: @CognitiveDesire. Yes I have it done. And It works fine where I use Text="{Binding Instance.Texts.GroupName, Source={StaticResource LocalizationManager}}" The question is how to do it for DATA.

Comment: You will have to have the data also translated. :(

Comment: @CognitiveDesire Can I use any pre-binding events and translate data?

Comment: try something like binding converter

Comment: @CognitiveDesire Good idea!!! Put it like an answer please. I am sure it should work!

Comment: You can try to use the DisplayName Attribute too. Its from DataAnnotations assembly.

Comment: @Vinicius Good good. Please ship me any sample.

Comment: check out this link : http://forums.silverlight.net/p/87399/202830.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using binding converter and use all primitive types having unicode feature in your database for already present database you will have to convert it your self